# An indication from convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading mathematical analysis of Laplace transform. The author stated that the convergence of the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t$$

indicates that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\tau_0 > 0$ such that

$$\left\lvert\int_{\tau}^\infty f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t\right\rvert < \epsilon$$

for all $\tau > \tau_{0}$. To me, intuitively it is correct. But how to prove it?

Comment: Hint. The integral is a converging limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt = M < \infty \iff \lim_{T \to \infty} F(T) =\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} f(t) dt = M <\infty$$
So it means that $F(T)$ must converge to $M$. From the definition of convergence it follows that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \tau_0$ s.t. if $T > \tau_0$ then $|F(T) - M|<\epsilon$.

In other words:
$$\bigg |\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt - \int_{0}^{\tau_0} f(t) dt \bigg | < \epsilon$$